# Loop, extract and calculate a series

Tags: r, loops

I have a data-frame which consists of **12** columns and **n** rows. I want to check the values from column 3:10 for each row. If the value is **1**, I want to calculate a series. Consider the following data-frame:

```
  A     B   b7  b6  b5   b4  b3  b2  b1  b0 
  0    190   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  1    700   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
  2    540   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

I want to loop through each row and check the value from **b7:b0**. if the value is **1**, then calculate the sum based on :
sum= (1* x^ (-position) ). based on the above example , sum should be:

1.**First row**  : sum= 1 * x ^ (-7)

2.**Second row** : sum= 1 * x ^ (-7) + 1 * x ^ (-0)

3.**Third row**   : sum= 1 * x ^ (-7) + 1 * x ^ (-1) + 1 * x ^ (-0)

where X is a constant value. The result should be added to the original data-frame :

```
  A     B   b7  b6  b5   b4  b3  b2  b1  b0 Result
  0    190   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   number
  1    700   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    ..
  2    540   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1    ..
```

For the splitting and extracting the data, I have followed two approaches( as best to my knowledge) whether to use **subset** or follow the classic way of splitting.

### Classic Approach

```
# loop through the data-frame ( here number of records n=3)
# df is the data-frame
for (i in 1:3){
 y<- df[i,3:10] 
}
```

---

```
# the above code extracts one row for each iteration with columns from b7:b0. gives an output :
b7  b6   b5   b4  b3  b2  b1  b0
1    0   0    0   0   0   1   1
```

Subset Approach

```
# Subset the df into new data-frame which only contains the b7:b0
  newDF<-subset.data.frame(df,select=b7:b0 )
```

---

My question, how to loop through the data-frame, check the values, and calculate the series. I'm only thinking to use many **IF** statements to check each value. I'm sure there are other alternatives approaches.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the loop in a `apply()` function:

```
df <- read.table(text =
"  A     B   b7  b6  b5   b4  b3  b2  b1  b0 
  0    190   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1    700   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2    540   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1",
header = TRUE)

X <- 3
df$Result <- apply(df[, 3:10], 1, function(row) sum(row * X ^ (-7:-0)))
df
#   A   B b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0       Result
# 1 0 190  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0.0004572474
# 2 1 700  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 1.0004572474
# 3 2 540  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1 1.3337905807
```

*Edit:* better solution from @jogo in the comments:

```
as.matrix(df[, 3:10]) %*% (1/X)^(7:0)
##              [,1]
## [1,] 0.0004572474
## [2,] 1.0004572474
## [3,] 1.3337905807
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need

Comment: with matrix multiplication: `as.matrix(df[, 3:10]) %*% (1/X)^(7:0)`

Comment: @jogo Added your solution to this answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `poly()` and matrix multiplication:

```
str <- "A,B,b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0 
0,190,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,540,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
1,700,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1"

file <- textConnection(str)

df <- read.table(file, header = T, sep = ",")
x <- 2
as.matrix(df[,3:10]) %*% rev(c(1, poly(x=1/x, degree=7, raw = TRUE)))
# > as.matrix(df[,3:10]) %*% rev(c(1, poly(x=1/x, degree=7, raw = TRUE)))
#           [,1]
# [1,] 0.0078125
# [2,] 1.5078125
# [3,] 1.0078125
```

I used the data definition from the answer of @Wietze314
variants:

```
as.matrix(df[,9:3]) %*% t(poly(x=1/x, degree=7, raw = TRUE)) + df$b0
tcrossprod(as.matrix(df[,9:3]), poly(x=1/x, degree=7, raw = TRUE)) + df$b0
```

Comment: Thank you for your smart response.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with a vector calculation and `apply` as follows

the data:

```
str <- "A,B,b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0 
0,190,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,540,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
1,700,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1"

file <- textConnection(str)

dat <- read.table(file, header = T, sep = ",")
x = 2
```

The method:

```
colSums(apply(dat[,3:10], 1, function(i) i*x^(-7:0)))
```

The result:

```
[1] 0.0078125 1.5078125 1.0078125
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.